# SUMIF - 2 worksheets run- time error 13

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs

I have been trying to solve this from quite few hours without any success. The code below is suppose to look in 2 different worksheets and calculate the total sum of a specific value.

In sheet 1 - column A we have unique values which are taken from sheet 2 - column G. Now the code below is suppose to take the unique value from sheet 1 - column A, verifies how many times the specific value is mentioned in sheet 2 - column G and sums up its total value from column N - sheet 2. The total sum will then be pasted in Sheet 1 - column F.

I am getting the **run-time error 13** after I declared the variables **lastrow1** and **lastrow2**. However, if I remove those variable from the code, I won't get any error, but the result will be **0** every time I run the code, which is not correct.

Can someone help me in finding a smarter way? Must appreciated!

I have re-changed the code and now it seems to work. My problem is that it puts the same value in all the cells (column F - from the sumif formula) which is not correct. How can I fix that?

```
   Sub sumvalueF()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long


   Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet2")

   lastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ws1.Range("F4:F" & lastrow).value = WorksheetFunction.sumif(ws.Range("g7:g30000"), ws1.Range("A4"), ws.Range("n7:n30000"))

    End Sub
```

Comment: First thing - that's not a good choice for a procedure name.  (Google: Excel VBA Reserved Words)

Comment: I was not aware of that, thanks!

Comment: You can't use a `Criteria` to your `SumIf` using a range, just a single value. What criteria you want to use for your `SumIf` ?

Comment: Just to understand, you mean criteria by this ` & lastrow1`?

Comment: @alex2002 See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-sumif-method-excel) should help.  If you print **the criteria** `Debug.Print "*" & ws1.Range("A4:A" & lastrow1) & "*"` after your `With` line, that may give a clue.  Also, I'd get the `SUMIF` working as a worksheet function, and then adapt it to VBA

Comment: I have tried now another approach, but I still get 0 as final result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ws1.Range("F4:F & lastrow").value` with `ws1.Range("F4:F" & lastrow).value`

EDIT
loop version:

```
For i = 4 To lastRow
ws1.Cells(i, 6).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ws.Range("g7:g30000"), ws1.Range("A"&i), ws.Range("n7:n30000"))
Next i
```

Comment: Yes, this is how it was set in my computer. I changed in the code as well. I have the same problem. The value from F4 is copied through all the cells in column F

Comment: Ofcourse is copied  through all the cells in column F because is that you set  here: `ws1.Range("F4:F & lastrow").value` You need a for loop for what you want. See edited post.